# Display correctly the selected value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use an AJAX to display my categories. My problem is when I select a category, the dropdown come back always at this initial position

For example, if I click "Panneaux lumineux", the dropdown go back to "Select your categorie" automatically. in this case "Panneaux lumineux" is not selected.

Tk

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myAjax").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://Admin/products_categories_ajax.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            //data returned from php
            var options_html = '<option value="">-- Select your categorie --</option>';
            for (index in data) {
              var category_id = data[index]['id'];
              var category_name = data[index]['text'];
              options_html += '<option value="' + category_id + '">' + category_name + '</option>';
            }
            $('#category_id').html(options_html);
          }
        });
      });
    })
  </script>
  <div id="myAjax">
    <select name="move_to_category_id" id="category_id">
      <option value="">-- Select your categorie --</option>
      <option value="0">Haut</option>
      <option value="25">Panneaux lumineux</option>
      <option value="23">Panneaux Signalétique</option>
      <option value="20">Signalétique Camping</option>
      <option value="22">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Barrières</option>
      <option value="21">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entrée</option>
    </select>
    <input name="current_category_id" value="20" type="hidden" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am not exactly sure what is the problem. I've been trying to reproduce your code in a jsbin https://jsbin.com/juvorazinu/edit?html,output
and i can correctly select 'Panneaux lumineux' for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have occurs, because your dropdown list is replaced with a new one when you click on the dropdown. Even if the dropdown is visually the same, it isn't in the DOM.

To solve it, you need to save the selected category ID and select it after the dropdown has been replaced.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myAjax").on('click', function () {
              var selectedCategory = $('select#category_id').val();
              $.ajax({
                url: 'http://Admin/products_categories_ajax.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                  //data returned from php
                  var options_html = '<option value="">-- Select your categorie --</option>';
                  for (var index in data) {
                    var category_id = data[index]['id'];
                    var category_name = data[index]['text'];
                    options_html += '<option value="' + category_id + '"' + (category_id == selectedCategory ? ' selected' : '') + '>' + category_name + '</option>';
                  }
                  $('#category_id').html(options_html);
                }

              });

            });
          })
        </script>
        <div id="myAjax">
            <select name="move_to_category_id" id="category_id">
                <option value="">-- Select your categorie --</option>
                <option value="0">Haut</option>
                <option value="25">Panneaux lumineux</option>
                <option value="23">Panneaux Signalétique</option>
                <option value="20">Signalétique Camping</option>
                <option value="22">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Barrières</option>
                <option value="21">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entrée</option>
            </select>
            <input name="current_category_id" value="20" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In that case we will need more info. Do you get console errors? Is the dropdown exactly the same? Are the category IDs the same?

Answer (score 0):

Above the
`$.ajax` function call
add

```
var selectedOptionVal = $('#category_id').val();
```

to save the value you selected.

then use that value to make the correct option selected when you recreate the html. So then try changing

```
for (index in data) {
    var category_id = data[index]['id'];
    var category_name = data[index]['text'];
    options_html += '<option value="' + category_id + '">' + category_name + '</option>';
}
```

to

```
for (var index in data) {
    var category_id = data[index]['id'];
    var category_name = data[index]['text'];
    var selectedString = category_id == selectedOptionVal ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    options_html += '<option value="' + category_id + '"' + selectedString + '>' + category_name + '</option>';
    }
```